# Regex pattern to replace and disable href links

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to disable `a` link tags (whose `href` attribute value starts with `log.html`) in my html table. I am trying to use string replace to do.

The code line looks approximately like this, `str.replace(/log.html...../g,'')` where there must be a regex pattern in the place of dots.

All patterns like this,

```
<a class="log" href="log.html#s1-s1-s1"></a>
<a class="log" href="log.html#s1-s2-s100"></a>
<a class="log" href="log.html#s10-s5-s1"></a>
```

must be made as,

```
<a class="log" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Okay, what's your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
/log.html#[^"]*/g
```

And replace with `#`

Code:

```
str.replace(/log.html#[^"]*/g,'#')
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aE6lU6/2)

Comment: Karthik, inside `<a>` tag, there can be classes defined. I tried putting a `*` betweeen `<a` and `\s` to extract those characters. It didn't work. My usecase is `<a class="log" href="log.html#s1-s2-s3">`. I will change the question accordingly but still mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Welcome.. and what is the problem if you have classes defined? still you get the same answer? if no? can you give sample output and input?

Comment: the first comment was applicable to the first regex you gave, when you were extracting the groups... with the present answer, it works...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `string.match()`. This function returns an array of the match and any captured groups. You could test all your links with something like this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    href = $(this).attr("href");
    if(href.match(/^log\.html/)) {
        $(this).attr("href", "#");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag24kdwy/)

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern seems to work given that the url is accessable as a string. This can easily be accomplished with jQuery.

```
 str.replace(/log\.html.*/g,'#')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since href and ".." are always available in a link, i would use a simple

```
/href=".+"/g
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aE6lU6/4)

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example?